# Can you click on any DOM element like a div and have it play audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I want to have an easter egg in my website where if you click on a div, then unexpectedly an audio file plays. Is that possible? I see the [audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) element, but that makes a whole audio player.

Comment: Why not make your audio player hidden? And then call `audioPlayer.play()` on div click?

Comment: I was able to acheive what I wanted through your link, thanks Adam!